# @Injectable({providedIn: Module}) => Circular dependency (ROUTES)

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular7

1. The VendasModule imports the router
2. that imports the father component
3. that imports the child component
4. That imports the SERVICE (That I want to be @injectable providedIn: VendasModule)
5. That imports the VendasModule (to be used in the @injectable decorator)
6. Circular dependency detected !

Any Ideas on how to go around this? I need all this imports, don't I?

```
VendasModule:
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(VendasRoutes),
    FlexLayoutModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    SharedModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgxCurrencyModule.forRoot(customCurrencyMaskConfig),
    CustomFormsModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
      ], (...)
```

```
VendasRouting:
export const VendasRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        canActivateChild: [Menu],
        children: [
            {
                path: 'cadastro-contrato',
                component: CadastroContratoComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'plano-comercial',
                component: PlanoComercialComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'check-list',
                component: CheckListComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'plano-emissoras',
                component: PlanoEmissorasComponent((FATHER COMPONENT))
            }

        ]
    }
]
```

```
Father Component:
export class PlanoEmissorasComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy { 
  @ViewChild(ProspectEmissorasComponent) prospectEmissoras: ProspectEmissorasComponent; ((Child Component))
  @ViewChild(NegociacaoEmissorasComponent) negociacaoEmissoras: NegociacaoEmissorasComponent;
  @ViewChild(FinancEmissorasComponent) financEmissoras: FinancEmissorasComponent;
  @ViewChild(ContratoEmissorasComponent) contratoEmissoras: ContratoEmissorasComponent;
```

```
Service:
import { VendasModule } from "../../../vendas.module";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: VendasModule
})
export class PlanoEmissorasService { ... }
```

I am getting this error:

```
WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
src/app/vendas/vendas.routing.ts -> src/app/vendas/cadastro-contrato/plano-emissoras/plano-emissoras.component.ts -> src/app/vendas/cadastro-contrato/plano-emissoras/prospect-emissoras/prospect-emissoras.component.ts -> src/app/vendas/cadastro-contrato/plano-emissoras/services/plano-emissoras.service.ts -> src/app/vendas/vendas.module.ts -> src/app/vendas/vendas.routing.ts
```

Comment: you should be using the `providers` array of VendasModule for providing service `plano-emissoras.service.ts` . Or make the service `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })`.

Answer (score 2):

The circular reference is in your code generated by the TypeScript compiler when it tries to resolve the circular imports. You can follow any of the below solutions:

1. Using the `providers` array of `VendasModule` for
   providing your service.
2. make the service `injectable` at root level: `@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root' })` which will help with tree-shaking.
3. Use `providedIn` in another module and import it in `VendasModule`

   ```
    @Injectable({ providedIn: SomeModule})
    export class PlanoEmissorasService {}
   ```

   Use this module in your VendasModule

   ```
    @NgModule({ imports: [SomeModule]})
    export class VendasModule
   ```

[Check this comment out on angular repo.](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10170#issuecomment-380673276)

Comment: Thanks a lot. The reason I want to do this is to DESTROY the service when user leaves VendasModule.

How can I do that? Ideas?

Comment: you can use the services from another module to prevent circular dependency issue. See Option #3 in my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot!

What I ended up doing was to use ngOnDestroy on the component to call ngOnDestroy() on the service and in this function I deleted all the vars I wanted.

The service still is providedIn 'root'

Comment: Yeah, That's a workaround that i am not a fan of. What i Prefer is to unsubscribe to the subscriptions on the component `ngOnDestroy`.

Comment: And how can I do that? hahahaha

Comment: @Yandiro, Check this example here for unsubscribe: https://alligator.io/angular/takeuntil-rxjs-unsubscribe/